# Lighting not showing in rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I'm using cycles render for this. My lamp which is a point lamp. It is in front a black plane and black text for my project. The lighting used to show up but stopped when I grouped it with the camera. Please help.

Comment: Could you please show the image and if you could link to your blend file that would be great.

Comment: The problem might be that you made your text 100% black, so no amount of light will illuminate it, try changing it to a very dark shade of grey but not black

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean the text is not showing up in a render.

It could be that you have the lamp on a separate layer, and isn't being rendered. Make sure you have the layer with the lamp on it selected when rendering.

Also, if you can't see the text at all, it could be because the text and background are so black that you can't even see them.